# Bootstrap collapse and accordion opens to side, not underneath

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap collapse but I want to keep my div-s with the content beneath each link, mainly because that's how i need it to work on mobile (the menu is a column and that the content opens under each link). Unfortunately, on website I have the links in a row, and the content doesn't open under the menu row of links, but to the side of each link. I don't want this to happen. Is there a way to keep my mark-up like this but to make the collapsed content open under the row of links?

```html
<div class="accordion main-navigation" id="accordion">
  <div class="main-menu-container">
    <nav class="main-menu navbar-collapse" id="hamburgerMenu">
      <ul class="main-nav p-0 m-0 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center">
        <li class="nav-item d-flex justify-content-start">
          <a class="mypage collapsed extend" data-toggle="collapse" href="#myPages" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="myPages">Mina sidor</a>
        </li>
        <div class="collapse mypage extended-navigation" id="mypage" data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul class="clearfix steg_down">
            <li class="drop-down">
              <div class="mega-menu row m-auto p-1 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3">
                <div class="col d-xs-none d-lg-block p-0">
                  <a href="#"><img src="..." alt="Placeholder Img"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <h3>Kontakta oss</h3>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Kontakta oss via telefon eller mail</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <h3>Hjälp</h3>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Ordlista</a></li>
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Missnöje</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item d-flex justify-content-start">
          <a class="kundservice collapsed extend" data-toggle="collapse" href="#kundservice" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="myPages">Kundservice</a>
        </li>
        <div class="collapse mypage extended-navigation" id="kundservice" data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul class="clearfix steg_down">
            <li class="drop-down">
              <div class="mega-menu row m-auto p-1 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3">
                <div class="col d-xs-none d-lg-block p-0">
                  <a href="#"><img src="..." alt="Placeholder Img"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <h3>Kontakta oss</h3>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Kontakta oss via telefon eller mail</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <h3>Hjälp</h3>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Ordlista</a></li>
                    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Missnöje</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <title>Page Title</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="accordion">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                    Your Accordian #1
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                  Your Accordian #2
                </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
                    Your Accordian #3
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can change the version of bootstrap i used in this file.